# Acessar variável dentro e fora de uma função em javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, escopo-de-variáveis

Estou tentando atualizar algumas questões numa página, percorrendo um _for com o número de passos igual ao total de questões, para em cada passagem injetar uma a questão via $.post(), e esperar o retorno para só então continuar o laço. Não sei se essa é a melhor forma a se realizar mas para essa situação que tenho, dois problemas surgiram:

1. Buscar variável externa dentro de um **function**
2. Impedir o fluxo do laço até que operação do *$.when* complete

O código que estou usando está abaixo:

```
function recalcularPesos(){

    //courseid=
    var id = ['1','2','3','4','5'];
    var passo = 0;
    for (p = 0; p < id.length; p++)
    {
        passo = passo+1;
        $.post("https://test.site.net/mod/quiz/edit_rest.php?class=resource&courseid="+id[p]).then(function()
            {
                console.log( passo+"a questão foi modificada" );
                if(passo = id.length){
                    console.log('passo: '+passo);
                    //Atualizar página após todas as atualizações
                    setTimeout(location.reload(), num*2000);
                }
            }, function() {
                alert( passo+"a questão NÃO modificada" );
            }
        );
    }   
}

recalcularPesos();
```

---

Da forma que estou fazendo ele precisa atualizar a página para mostrar os valores atualizados das questões, mas a página está sendo atualizada antes mesmo de completar todos os posts (se forem muitas questões, pior). Observei ainda que a variável **passo** retorna no terminal em todos os passos da iteração, o valor máximo (**5**,nesse caso).

Comment: Ficou meio confuso. O que está tentando fazer?

Comment: De onde vem esse `courseid`?

Comment: O meu real objetivo é enviar as novas notas das questões para modificá-las, mas como no código original haviam muitas buscas/parâmetros (como o id da questão, variável com número de questões, sessão da página), resolvi enxugar o código acima. Resumindo. Preciso em cada passo do __for__ injetar por $.post() os dados da questão com sua nova nota, mas só passar para o próximo passo quando concluir o anterior, e só ao término de todos, atualizar a página. O problema aí é que não consigo buscar as variáveis _passo_ e _id_ dentro do _function_ mais interno. P.S. sou leigo.

Comment: __Corrigi o nome da variável.__ É pq reduzi o código para ficar mais claro onde seria o problema, e acabei confundindo os nomes delas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Atualização:**
Usar `for` não é recomendado por ser *assíncrono*, ou seja, vai ficar dando loop sem esperar o retorno do `$.when`.

O `location.reload()` no `setTimeout` deve estar entre aspas.

Você pode reinvocar a função `recalcularPesos()` sempre que a URL invocada no `$.post` enviar um retorno positivo, fazendo um loop até o limite de itens na array `id`:

```
var id = ['1','2','3','4','5'];
passo = 0;
function recalcularPesos(){
    if(passo < id.length){
        $.post("https://test.site.net/mod/quiz/edit_rest.php?class=resource&courseid="+id[passo]).then(
        function(){
            console.log( id[passo]+" a questão foi modificada" );
            passo++;
            recalcularPesos();
        },
        function() {
            console.log( id[passo]+" a questão NÃO modificada" );
        });
    }else{
        // aqui termina o loop
        setTimeout("location.reload()",2000);
    }
}

recalcularPesos();
```

> Note que coloquei a Array fora da função(!) para ela não ficar repetindo.

Comment: Rapaz! Era isso mesmo que eu procurava! E valeu pelas várias dicas meu caro @Dvdsamm!

Comment: @GabrielOliveira Prazer ter sido útil! Boa sorte!